# Parameters of a discrete SIR model and Euler’s formulas for SIR model.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

What is the difference between parameters of a discrete SIR model (infection rate and recovery rate), shown below:

[image]

And parameters of Euler formulas shown below if we consider the same data.
[image]

Can I use the discrete SIR model to estimate parameters of spread of a disease in a specific city and apply those parameters to Euler’s formulas above for the same city?
I thought if the step size = 1 in Euler formulas, then parameters will be the same as discrete SIR model, but I found myself more confused when I decided to research further. Please help.

Comment: It is about the same difference as the difference between nominal and effective interest rate. (And of course, if the time step is too large, then the discretized process may exhibit limit cycles or become chaotic.)

Comment: @Lutz, I'm sorry I have no idea what you are talking about. What does that mean in simple words?

Comment: The nominal interest rate is annual and used linearly. One would have to consult literature on how the daily interest rate is actually computed, for instance as $r/365$. Then the effective annual interest rate is $(1+r/365)^{365}-1$, which is closer to $e^r-1$ than to $r$. A similar relation exists between your constant parameters if $\Delta t$ is a fraction of one day. Of course you have also to care that the variables in the first model are population numbers while in the second they are population densities.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, thanks for the insight. Now, suppose I have estimated the parameters from discrete SIR model, what can I do to apply them in the Euler's formulas for the same data?

Comment: If the Euler model has step size = 1 day, then the rates should be the same to reproduce the same result (taking into account $s_k=S_k/N$). If the step size is smaller, there is no ready-made translation, you would have to start a new estimation process, but you can take the 1d parameters as initial point.

Comment: Perfect, thanks